# Why do I have to redeploy my application every time I restart Glassfish?

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I'm a first time user on stack overflow and new to Glassfish.

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 and Glassfish 5.0, my application is using Primefaces and JSF.

I can deploy my application successfully to Glassfish using NetBeans or via a .war file, but every time I restart Glassfish I get a 404 error when I try to access my web application. I then need to redeploy my application for it to work again. I am able to redeploy via NetBeans without issue, but need to undeploy before redeploying if using a .war file.

I have a test application running on the same server that is not impacted by the restart.

I've looked at similar issues on stack overflow and tried modifying my web.xml but this doesn't seem to help. I suspect this is a configuration error on my part, here is my web.xml.

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE Production</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

I was expecting the web application to be unaffected by a Glassfish server restart, but it requires redeployment for it to run successfully after a restart.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you running Windows by any chance ? GlassFish and Payara are, in my experience, unreliable under Windows - which frankly is not suitable for any serious development work anyway. Windows and NTFS in particular tends to behave pretty strangely, causing almost undefined behavior. If this is the case, switch development environment and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I've been unwell. My GlassFish instance is running under Ubuntu although I am developing under Windows and deploying to the instance. I have looked at lots of other solutions online but still haven't solved my problem.